# Upload file test with Postman

Tags: postman, sharepoint-online

I am testing a file upload to SharePoint online with Postman. In my post request I set the body to form-data and add a file param with a text file called a.txt. The text file contains the text

```
one
two
three
```

When I execute the request my file is uploaded but when I open the file the contents is

```
----------------------------235004993628819232914336
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

one
two
three
----------------------------235004
```

I have tried setting the Content-Type header to

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
or
multipart/form-data

But no luck

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please follow the below steps-

```
1. Go to the body of the API
2. pass the parameter or key
3. When you pass the key you have a option of value of Text/File like below
4.Choose the file from
5. Click on send.
6. Get your response.
```

Hope this helps buddy.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case setting the body to type binary solved my problem with testing with Postman

Comment: That (type binary) worked for me as well, despite the file being a text file - it stops Postman from adding metadata headers/footers.