# File Uploads via FormModel (Official description), but form.is_valid is always false

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to use FormModel to handle a file upload, but form.is_valid() is always returning false, and never shows any kind of error.Following is the code snippet from models.py,forms.py,views.py and my POST request.

### models.py

```
class Pics(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to=img_path)
```

### forms.py

```
class PicsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pics
        fields = ['username','path']
```

### views.py

```
def uploads(request:HttpRequest):
    form = PicsForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # instance = Pics(username=request.POST['username'],path=request.FILES['file'])
        # instance.save()
        form.save()
        print('***')
    else:
        print('&&&&&&&&&&&&&')
    return HttpResponse("succeed")
```

[here is my postman set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8SGx.png)

I expect the output of '***', but the actual output is '&&&&&&&&&&&&&'

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534711/8224266). Might be of use.

Comment: I think I exactly did like this

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your html form has 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' and your file upload input has name 'path', for example, your form should be like:

```
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <input type="file" name="path">
</form>
```

Comment: I am sure I've set content-type= multipart/form-data in Postman, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Postman is not setting a CSRF token.  Is there a reason that you are testing with Postman rather than creating an HTML form and submitting to it through your browser?  I would do the latter, and if there is still a problem you could show us your template.

Comment: When `form.is_valid()` returns `False` there must be errors in the form validation, so try looking at `form.path.errors()` and `form.non_field_errors()`